# JPEG decompression inconsistent across Windows architectures

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, jpeg

I am testing JPEG decompression on a bunch of computers with different versions of Windows. All of these computers have .NET 4 installed and I am compiling against .NET 2 and the "Any CPU" platform target. The following code produces different output on different systems.

```
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile("test.jpg");

long datasum = 0;
for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
    for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
        datasum = datasum + bmp.GetPixel(x, y).R + bmp.GetPixel(x, y).G + bmp.GetPixel(x, y).B;

Console.WriteLine(datasum);
```

All the Win7 64-bit and WinXP 32-bit machines produce one result. And all the Win7 32-bit machines produce another result.

Any ideas why the output would be different?

Comment: How different?  JPEG is a lossy compression.  During reconstruction you could be running into floating-point differences during the inverse-dct, the color-transform or the dequantization.

Comment: I used a 512x512 image with a lot of black and I am getting 5590758 and 5591908 for the results. While the difference is small I dont understand why XP would match Win7-64 but not Win7-32. Perhaps there is a document or site that explains such behavior?

Comment: Are you really that curious about jpeg decompression?  Or is there a larger issue at work here?

Comment: I am working on a scientific application that requires JPEGs to be decoded exactly the same across platforms. Unfortunately my source only provides JPEGs and not a bitmap type.

Comment: I suggest using a utility to convert the format and possibly distributing the converted files instead of the JPEG. The consistency you're asking for is not a reasonable requirement for JPEGs.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control of the JPEGs we receive as input. I only have control over how they get decoded.

Comment: I made a similar experience some years ago. One point of image (and video) compression is, that the decoders are defined to behave the same way everywhere! The magic lies in the encoder. So, by definition, you shouldn't have any differences and if Microsoft does its business the right way, then I guess that this effect comes from some operation before or after the JPEG decoding. You may try an alternative like this: http://code.google.com/p/fjcore/

Answer (score 1):

It's implemented by gdiplus.dll. Check which versions are actually loaded on different system, and bitness.

There may be floating-point issue, MMX instructions allowed on one machine, not the other.

Comment: I have many gdiplus.dll of various versions in c:\windows\winsxs\ . How do I know which one to look at? I will say that I did check the versions of c:\windows\system32\gdi32.dll across machines. The version on the Win7 machines (both 32 and 64 bit) are the same. The version on the XP machines do not match the Win7 machines. These differences do not reflect my observations made in my original question.

Comment: debugger, tlist, vmmap, process explorer can tell.

Comment: Both win7 32 and 64 bit are using version 6.1.7601 for gdi32.dll gdiplus.dll and WindowsCodecs.dll. Win XP is using gdi32.dll version 5.1.2600.5698, gidplus.dll version 5.2.6002.22791, and WindowsCodecs.dll 6.0.6001.17009.

Answer (score 1):

Can be related to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4sahykhd.aspx).

Try setting useEmbeddedColorManagement parameter to true.

Comment: Great idea. Just tried it, but it did not affect the results.

Comment: Btw, can you try same with a Bitmap? So that we can be more specific about the problem. Also, which service pack is installed on your WinXP ?

Comment: Setting useEmbeddedColorManagement to true or false does not affect the results. When I try this with a Bitmap file instead of a Jpeg file, the sum is consistent across all these platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost afraid to suggest this, but what if you find or implement your own jpeg decoder?  Go old school & rely on the infrastructure to do nothing more than give you a stream of bytes.

It would be a major pain to do, but could eliminate the inconsistencies you're seeing.

Comment: Its a good idea, and I would certainly not rule it out. I am still curious where exactly the above problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [latest version of GDI+](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18909) on all machines and try again.

Also, if you decide to implement yourself, I've found [this sample](http://www.xbdev.net/image_formats/jpeg/jpeg_decoder_source/index.php) useful in the past.

Answer (score 0):

this is not your answer , I just passed half of the way .

I think the best solution is using your own JPEG decoder, I found source code for that : [Mini Jpeg Decoder](http://www.h4ck3r.net/2009/12/02/mini-jpeg-decoder/) but it's in C++ , I deploy that to Win32 dll file , you can find it [here](http://mironline.net/_tmp/MiniJpegDecoder.rar) . it's over 10 hours that I'm working to use that in .net framework , but I wasn't success! because I haven't got any clue about c++.