# c# Image scaling quality different between dev and production environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-resizing

i have created a function that resizes and crops a picture and then saves the resulting image file.
In my development environment it works just great, but on production the resulting image is "grainy".
You can see the different quality here http://test.powersport.it/canc2.aspx

Here is the code that generates the resized and cropped image

```
    // width: width of cropped img - height: height of cropped img
    System.Drawing.Bitmap thumbnail = new Bitmap(width, height);
    // image: original System.Drawing.Image containing full size img
    thumbnail.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);
    // size[0]: width of resized img - size[1]: height of resized image
    System.Drawing.Image mini = new Bitmap(image, size[0], size[1]);
    System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(thumbnail);

    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

    g.DrawImage(mini, ((width - size[0]) / 2), ((height - size[1]) / 2), size[0], size[1]);

    EncoderParameters encoderParameters;
    encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
    ImageCodecInfo[] info = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();

    // img: original file name
    switch (Path.GetExtension(img).ToLower())
    {
        case ".png": //       info[4]
            thumbnail.Save(dest, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            break;
        case ".bmp": //       info[0]
            thumbnail.Save(dest, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            break;
        case ".tiff": //      info[3]
            encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Compression, (long)EncoderValue.CompressionLZW);
            thumbnail.Save(dest, info[3], encoderParameters);
            break;
        case ".tif": //      info[3]
            encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Compression, (long)EncoderValue.CompressionLZW);
            thumbnail.Save(dest, info[3], encoderParameters);
            break;
        default: //jpeg      info[1]
            encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, compression);
            thumbnail.Save(dest, info[1], encoderParameters);
            break;
    }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE**: i've tried with PNG, BMP and TIFF but they have the same problem

Comment: What's the `compression` argument you are feeding into `encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, compression);` for jpeg images?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to specify that `compression` is a parameter of my function, in this case its value is 100 (both dev and production)

Comment: Does it have the same problem for all file types, png, bmp, tiff, etc. or just for one of them, if so which one?

Comment: It has the same problem with other file types as you can see in the page i have linked above (i updated it). I tried with png, bmp and tif.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite an interesting one, and based on the fact you are supplying `compression=100` you might think that no compression at all should be applied.

Unfortunately, according to the [MSDN article on setting the JPEG Compression Level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> A quality level of 0 corresponds to the greatest compression, and a
>   quality level of 100 corresponds to the least compression.

So `100` does not mean no compression, it means the least compression possible.

As for it varying from machine to machine, this is fairly consistent - I have observed this, and there's even a number of other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872850/jpeg-decompression-inconsistent-across-windows-architectures) on Stack Overflow.

As the actual mechanics of the compression are handled by GDI+ (outside of the .Net Framework) then it will depend on the actual version installed on the machines.

Comment: Being JPEG a compressed format i was aware that setting `100` was still compressing the image. But i thought it would've given the same result on the two machines. At this point, what would be the best way to have nice quality scaled images? Use 3rd party components?

Comment: I'd consider using a file format like PNG instead and convert to that, just for a free comparitive method, for your thumbnails. There are 3rd party implementations for image encoding but I believe they aren't free, or you could try using this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83225/A-Simple-JPEG-Encoder-in-C

Comment: @Dez If it's only JPEG that this happens on, can you ignore that format and go with bmp or png instead? Though ignoring it doesn't fix the problem so would be really interested in the correct answer

Comment: @harag the answer is really to use a machine independent jpeg encoder or decoder but they usually cost money. Or to use PNG or BMP as you mention.

Comment: @dash I thought that might be the case, I've always had problems with Jpegs in the past because of compression so try to stick with bmp or png.

Comment: @dash the problem happens with other file types. I have updated the linked page.

Comment: That's annoying. What versions of Windows are your DEV and Prod servers? Are you sure your source images are the same?

Comment: My dev server is Windows Web Server 2008 R2 SP1 while the production one is Windows Web Server 2008 SP2. I'm 100% sure the source image is the same, because i downloaded it on purpose to test better on dev environment.

Answer (score 1):

#### You're assuming that each machine has exactly the same encoders at exactly the same indexes.

It's likely each machine is actually compressing images in a different format, depspite the file extension.

WS2008 and WS2008 R2 have different graphics subsystems. In the latter, GDI+ is just a wrapper for the WIC encoders, which have a different sent of quirks.

I really hope you decide to [use a library that handles these differences for you](http://imageresizing.net). Server-side imaging is neither simple nor intuitive, and [has an endless list of pitfalls to avoid](http://www.nathanaeljones.com/blog/2009/20-image-resizing-pitfalls). Aside from the encoding issues you're having here, it looks like you're under the impression .NET will actually garbage collect classes from the `System.Drawing` namespace. It won't, and you're going to have some serious stability issues unless every reference is inside a `using(){}` clause.